# Running C Code from Github in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, github, visual-studio-code, qt-creator

I wanted to play around with the Live Motion code I found on github at this [link](https://github.com/tschnz/Live-Video-Magnification).

I am fairly new but I thought that all I need to do is clone and download the link. I opened it in VS code (I ran the hello world code in c++ so I assume I have configured it properly). I basically cloned the repository and all files and folders appeared as follows:

[image]

However, I am confused as to how I can run the entire project. Previously I would just click on the project name, build, and it would create the exe file. That doesn't seem to exist for cloning the repo.

I need some basic guidance to how I simply run the entire project from github.

I did install QT Creator 5.9.9 and it also shows up in my Visual Studio.

But I am still unsure about how to run the software and if anyone was able to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like you have QT downloaded and or linked correctly. You'll need to install that. And also, please no pictures of code, copy and paste it into a code block.

Comment: Qt is not going to be easy (not a beginner topic) with Visual Studio Code. It requires executing moc / uic ... Unless this is a requirement your task will be much simpler using `qt-creator`.

Comment: In the `src` folder there is a .pro file which is used by QMake / qt-creator as the project file. My advice is to install Qt and Qt-Creator using the online installer found in the Qt downloads. [https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer)

Comment: I downloaded QT Creator and it shows up in Visual Studio as well. Do I even need VS if all I have to do is compile and run the .pro file and all the folders in QT Creator?